# In OPP JS can you access a method declared inside a prototype function from the constructor?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm reading about OPP js and while going over an example and was wondering if in:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;

}

Person.prototype.sayName = function(){

        var tempName = this.name;

        var saySomething = function(){

            console.log(tempName);

    }
    //return saySomething();
}

var person1 = new Person('chris');
```

is theres a way to fire the saySomething method from the constructor.
eg.

```
person1.sayName().saySomething() //which doesnt work obviously
```

Comment: And no, `saySomething` is a local variable, and can't be called outside `sayName`, you have to return a reference or use `this` to add it as a property

Comment: @j08691 oh you know me

Comment: @adeneo how would you use "this" to accomplish that?

Comment: `this.saySomething = function() {....`

Comment: @adeneo I cant get that to work in the prototype method of sayName. Did you mean to just make it apart of the constructer function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning an object when `sayName` will work:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayName = function() {

    var tempName = this.name;

    return {
        saySomething: function() {
            console.log(tempName);
        }
    };
};

var person1 = new Person('chris');
person1.sayName().saySomething(); // logs 'chris'
```

Comment: Please show how the OP would use this to solve their problem.

Comment: Well jfriend00 without complicating things the above solution will allow the OP to call the method `saySomething` defined in `sayName`.

Comment: Yeah one can do this, but you've used a complicated structure without a problem that seems to warrant it.  Why create a closure here?  Why return an object with a method from `sayName()`? What problem are you actually solving?  Code should be kept as simple as possible and made no more complicated than warranted by the problem at hand.

Comment: I must disagree with your last phrase. The above code is as simple as it can be as a solution to the OPs question. Go ahead execute what I posted and you'll see that it works. Although your answer is helpful I don't see how it helps this exact question. He asked `is there a way to fire the saySomething method from the constructor` and since he's learning OOP I presume he already knows how to create global functions.

Comment: The only problem I've seen explained is how to call a function `saySomething()` which does something very simple from multiple places.  I offered the simplest possible solution to that problem.  You constrained the problem to not moving the `saySomething()` code to a better place where it can be more easily shared.  I think that just created a more complicated solution than is needed.  That's my opinion based on the problem described so far.  The question is a bit lacking in specifics so there's plenty of room for guessing what they really meant.

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe that OP wants to know how to call a function defined in the local scope of a certain prototype method. What you explained is how to create a global function which logs its parameter..

Comment: This is what I was looking for @CatalinMunteanu I dont know enough to know what kind of problems I would solve with something like this but to know that this is possible and how it could be done is what I was looking for.